# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty.Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a comments controller.But when rails render form, browser show an error 'First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty', though the variable is defined.

there is comments_controller

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController
        def new
        end

        def create
            @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
            if @comment.save
                redirect_to root_url
            else
                render 'static_pages/home'
            end
        end

         private

        def comment_params
          params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
        end
    end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :text %><br><br>
<% end %>
```

how fix?
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix :-

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
  # ....
end
```

Comment: From what you've provided, it is tough to say why. Instead of exception backtrace, could you paste your `new.html.erb` action?